# Is it possible to replace in a contenteditable without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I would like to know if it is possible to replace 
 tags with something else in the following contenteditable without having to reload the page :

```
<div class="noteentry" onfocus="updateident(this);" id="entry'.$row['id'].'" data-ph="Enter text here" contenteditable="true">'.$entryfinal.'</div>
```

I replace the 
 tags through javascript by lauching the updateident function when focus is on the contenteditable area:

```
var ent = ent.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "&nbsp;<br>");
```

The js above works well, I then get the ent content and write it to an html file.

However, the modifications are applied in my webpage only when I reload the page because, it reads the html file stored.

Is it possible to apply the modifications as I modify the content? For example if I paste some lines of text.

In case it helps:

For the full script, see on Github line 375 :

https://github.com/Pozinux/cnot/blob/main/app/index.php

For the demo of the website :
https://cnot.fr/     (password -> password)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding to my function :

```
function updateident(el)
{
    ...
    var str = document.getElementById("entry"+editingnote).innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "&nbsp;<br>");
    document.getElementById("entry"+editingnote).innerHTML = res;
}
```